# Crash when running unit test target using XCode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This Only happens in XCode 7 using iOS 9 SDK - the error is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in line `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` in the `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Also see a bunch of log output looking like:
`ObjectiveC.gcda: cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag (0x614e6269)`

Stacktrace:

```
#0  0x017a71e6 in llvm_gcda_emit_function ()
#1  0x001a8556 in __llvm_gcov_writeout ()
#2  0x017a8162 in llvm_writeout_files ()
#3  0x07a400bc in __cxa_finalize_ranges ()
#4  0x07a40159 in __cxa_finalize ()
#5  0x07a40474 in exit ()
#6  0x05cdd099 in ___XCTestMain_block_invoke ()
#7  0x05cdd0b3 in ___XCTestMain_block_invoke_2 ()
#8  0x05c89122 in -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] ()
#9  0x05c8a128 in -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] ()
#10 0x05c8a5fd in -[XCTestDriver runTestConfiguration:completionHandler:] ()
#11 0x05cdce12 in _XCTestMain ()
#12 0x025f85eb in ____XCBundleInjection_block_invoke_2 ()
#13 0x06b9ad00 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#14 0x06b90683 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#15 0x06b8fdb8 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x06b8f706 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x06b8f51b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#18 0x0879c664 in GSEventRunModal ()
#19 0x0879c4a1 in GSEventRun ()
#20 0x047dc28f in UIApplicationMain ()
#21 0x00400794 in main at /Users/al/dev/ios/hinge-dev/Hinge/main.m:18
#22 0x07992a21 in start ()
```

I've tried changing a bunch of XCode build settings to disable code coverage but no success. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Disabling code coverage in all build targets fixed this issue, answer here: [Dozens of "profiling:invalid arc tag" when running code coverage in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519530/dozens-of-profilinginvalid-arc-tag-when-running-code-coverage-in-xcode-5)

Comment: @amleszk Disabling code coverage is the only thing that you did for your case. Could you highlight if you have done something additional to make test case not to crash?